# How to append a String to another String?

Tags: string, concatenation, rust

If I have two `String`s, how do I append one to the other using stable Rust? It's a simple question but stackoverflow doesn't think I am verbose enough apparently. This is some extra text.

Comment: Ever heard of google? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html#concatenation

Comment: Yes I tried googling but that did not come up. Also that isn't mentioned in the reference documentation for `String`.

Comment: You can try googling with spesific keyword like this : `string concatenation rust` . It works, trust me :))

Comment: @Timmmm I don't know anything about rust but I just googled it and picked the most reliable source and BAM! there is the solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html#concatenation)

> If you have a String, you can concatenate a &str to the end of it:
>
> `let hello = "Hello ".to_string(); let world = "world!";`
>
> `let hello_world = hello + world;`
>
> But if you have two Strings, you need an &:
>
> `let hello = "Hello ".to_string();`
>
> `let world = "world!".to_string();`
>
> `let hello_world = hello + &world;`

Comment: Ah yes, it was the automatic coersion from `String` to `&str` using `&` that I didn't know about. I was trying to use `as_str()` but it isn't available yet. Thanks! (Also might be worth mentioning `push_str()`.

Comment: Note that `to_string` on `&str`s is inefficient. Use `into` or `to_owned` instead.